# Why I'm getting syntax error in SQL statement for a variable containing email address?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax-error, sql-insert

I'm using **PHP, MySQL and PHPMyAdmin**

Following is the code from PHP file :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_login (user_id, email, token)
  VALUES ($user_id, $email, $token)";
```

I got following error for above query :

```
Error: INSERT INTO user_login (user_id, email, token)
  VALUES (303, mrp7590@kastate.edu, 68e1f6cbea3b7a0b77a28395f4a8fef8449c23b1b00a392aa43451a0bfd5ff0e)<br>You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@kastate.edu, ise152e16e36393037933be10ac8a6f6de9e257a5d85e008bbd379bae20b5f535b)' at line 2
```

Can some one please correct the mistake I'm making in the above insert query?

Thanks.

Comment: SQL expects string values to be quoted... but you shouldn't be injecting values directly into an SQL statement, but using bind vars anyway

Comment: Any reason for not using prepared statement?

Answer (score 3):

`$sql = "INSERT INTO user_login (user_id, email, token)
  VALUES ($user_id, '$email', '$token')";`

Answer (score 1):

you must enclose it with single quotes

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_login (user_id, email, token)
VALUES ($user_id, '$email', '$token')";
```

like this one

```
INSERT INTO user_login (user_id, email, token)
VALUES (303,'mrp7590@kastate.edu','68e1f6cbea3b7a0b77a28395f4a8fef8449c23b1b00a392aa43451a0bfd5ff0e')
```